# How to see override functions and template files in use for any part of the drupal site?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I remember there is a module for displaying which core or theme functions or template files are used in order to create any part of a drupal site. Has anyone know what is the name of this module?

I need this module in site building.
Thanks in advance.

gokhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about the [Theme Developer](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module.  When you install and enable, it you can click on just about any properly rendered element and see

- Preprocess and process function candidates
- Theme function candidates
- Template file suggestions

Just keep in mind that it can interfere with some themes, and doesn't work well in some versions of IE.